# X axis values Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba

I found this code in StackOverflow to create dynamic excel charts

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SetSourceData _
         Source:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("MyRange")
```

It works fine, the only issue is the x-axis values are 1,2,3,4,5 etc..

I would like to select another range for the x-values. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Chart.Axes(xlCategory)` to get a reference to the x-axis (see documentation for this method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839276%28v=office.15%29.aspx)), then set whatever properties you want on that object. For instance:

```
Dim theChart As Chart
Set theChart = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Chart

theChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 0.1
theChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 1.1
theChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 0.25
theChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnit = 0.05
```

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195770%28v=office.15%29.aspx) shows the properties that are available on an `Axis` object.